# send keys to a third party window from vba by hWnd

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to send a keystroke to a third party window. Sounds simple, yes? Doesn't mean I'm getting it...

I'm working within a fairly heavily locked down system so I'm limited as to what data I can access and what programs I can use, hence why I'm using VBA and not a stand alone compiler.

The window in question identifies as "WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.33c0d9d" and it opens whenever a user attempts to send an email (to force users to include a protective marking on every email).

I effectively need to send either a {space} or an {enter} (yes, I'm thinking sendkeys for simplicity sake) to this window to allow full automation. As it stands, the user is having to click OK on the window with each emailed report.

The window itself does not have a visible title when it displays.

I assume it is possible to bring this window to the front by the windows handle and then send the keystroke to it, but I'm a little stumped on how to get there.

I've done some research and have cobbled together the following code which will provide me with the windows handle but that's about as far as I've managed to get. Tried tacking on a sendkeys which isn't doing anything and I'm out of ideas.

```
Dim DeskTophWnd As Long, WindowhWnd As Long

Dim Buff As String * 255, WindowsCaption() As String

Dim WindowsHandle() As Long

Dim lngret As Long

Dim strtext As String

ReDim WindowsCaption(0)

ReDim WindowsHandle(0)

DeskTophWnd = GetDesktopWindow

WindowhWnd = GetWindow(DeskTophWnd, 5)

Do While (WindowhWnd <> 0)

    GetWindowText WindowhWnd, Buff, 255

    strtext = String$(100, Chr$(0))

    lngret = GetClassName(hwnd, strtext, 100)

    If (Trim(Buff) <> "") And (IsWindowVisible(WindowhWnd) > False) Then

        'ShowWindowAsync WindowhWnd, 0

        ReDim Preserve WindowsCaption(UBound(WindowsCaption) + 1)

        ReDim Preserve WindowsHandle(UBound(WindowsHandle) + 1)

        WindowsCaption(UBound(WindowsCaption)) = Buff

        WindowsHandle(UBound(WindowsHandle)) = WindowhWnd

    End If

    WindowhWnd = GetWindow(WindowhWnd, 2)

    msgbox WindowhWnd

    if left(buff, 31)= "Protective Markings for Outlook" then sendkeys "{ENTER}", true


Loop

'The caption of window is in WindowsCaption()

'The handle of window is in WindowsHandle()
```

If anyone can assist, it would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

M

Comment: it gives you an error? or simply no result?

Comment: Simply no result I'm afraid.

Comment: In order to utilize the hwnd library, you need to declare it, this would be the windows DLL "User32". Such as: `Public Declare Function SetActiveWindow Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long`. Additionally, using `SendKeys` is notoriously dangerous, I am sure you know that, but I'd just like to make that clear for your sake in case you do not.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code: in excel (or access) paste this into a new module; try to open the window on which you have to send the keys, run this module and then press Ctrl-G to popup the debugger; here there is the list of all the title of the windows opened in this time. Find your title and then copy here in the code in the part of `CaptionWindowsString`; put your sendkeys in the statement `sendkeys` and try.
You can make a try with another window (ie notepad.exe)

```
Option Explicit
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "USER32" () As LongPtr
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindow Lib "USER32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal wCmd As Long) As LongPtr
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowText Lib "USER32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As LongPtr) As Long

    Sub oleee()
    Dim DeskTophWnd As LongPtr
    Dim WindowhWnd As LongPtr
    Dim Buff As String * 255
    Dim strtext As String
    Dim hwnd As Long
    Dim CaptionWindowsString As String

    CaptionWindowsString = "insert here the title(or part) of the window"
    CaptionWindowsString = "Blocco"
    DeskTophWnd = GetDesktopWindow
    WindowhWnd = GetWindow(DeskTophWnd, 5)
    Do While (WindowhWnd <> 0)
        Buff = String$(255, Chr$(0))
        GetWindowText WindowhWnd, Buff, 255
        Debug.Print Buff
        strtext = String$(100, Chr$(0))
        WindowhWnd = GetWindow(WindowhWnd, 2)

        If InStr(Buff, CaptionWindowsString) <> 0 Then
            AppActivate Buff, True
            DoEvents
            SendKeys "inser here the string of keys to send", True
            DoEvents
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    End Sub
```